# Timeline option "create video animation" does not appear

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation

Usually when animating in Photoshop, you enable the timeline bar and choose between "create frame animation" and "create video animation".
However, on my PS 2022, that I bought recently, I only have one option, which is "create frame animation". I can not find the other option anywhere…

Even my professor at university did not know how to solve it - he recommended de- and reinstalling the program. Unfortunately, it did not help.

IF anyone knows how to solve that problem, I would be very grateful for that.

Thank you in advance, kind regards
Theresa[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Tech support is generally off topic here, but [see the second issue listed here](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/photoshop-for-apple-silicon.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an M1 mac?
Try this

Right-Click on the Photoshop icon in your application folder.
click "get info" and make sure "open with rosetta" is checked